# Can Cydia apps make use of the UIFileSharingEnabled option?

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak, file-sharing, cydia

Regular iOS App Store apps can exchange files with computers via iTunes by turning on `UIFileSharingEnabled` in their Info.plist. The files exchanged are placed in and/or retrieved from the `Documents` directory for the app. Jailbreak/Cydia apps, being System apps, don't have such a directory--so I'm assuming they can't use this feature to exchange files with a computer? (Obviously jailbreak devices have more options to exchange files like ssh.)

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm talking about system apps, not regular apps that happen to be headed for Cydia for whatever reason.

Comment: I'm guessing this won't be possible, but I'd like to have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Cydia apps can be built using all the features as a normal app IF you are using X-Code

Comment: I'm actually using Xcode, but I still don't know how UIFileSharingEnabled would work for *system apps*, not regular apps that happen to be in Cydia. Maybe I should have myself clearer in the question.